# jquery bookmark links

Tags: jquery, bookmark

I got social bookmarks in jQuery, but how can I get post titles and permalinks in this snippet? If I put `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` in there, the whole site gets blank.

```
$('a[rel=shareit-twitter]').attr('href', 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + title + '%20-%20' + title);
```

UPDATE:

Here's the whole jQuery for the bookmarking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(
    function() {
         //grab all the anchor tag with rel set to shareit
    $('a[rel=shareit], #shareit-box').click(function(e) {      
         e.preventDefault();
        //get the height, top and calculate the left value for the sharebox
        var height = $(this).height();
        var top = $(this).offset().top;

        //get the left and find the center value
        var left = $(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() /2) - ($('#shareit-box').width() / 2);     

        //grab the href value and explode the bar symbol to grab the url and title
        //the content should be in this format url|title
        var value = $(this).attr('href').split('|');

        //assign the value to variables and encode it to url friendly
        var field = value[0];
        var url = encodeURIComponent(value[0]);
        var title = encodeURIComponent(value[1]);

        //assign the height for the header, so that the link is cover
        $('#shareit-header').height(height);

        //display the box
        $('#shareit-box').show();

        //set the position, the box should appear under the link and centered
        $('#shareit-box').css({'top':top, 'left':left});

        //assign the url to the textfield
        $('#shareit-field').val(field);

        //make the bookmark media open in new tab/window
        $('a.shareit-sm').attr('target','_blank');

        //Setup the bookmark media url and title
        $('a[rel=shareit-mail]').attr('href', 'http://mailto:?subject=' + title);
        $('a[rel=shareit-facebook]').attr('href', 'http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=' + url + '&title=' + title);
        $('a[rel=shareit-posterous]').attr('href', 'http://posterous.com/share?linkto=' + url + '&title=' + title);
        $('a[rel=shareit-twitter]').attr('href', 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + title + '%20-%20' + title);
    });

    //onmouse out hide the shareit box
    $('#shareit-box').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#shareit-field').val('');
        $(this).hide();
    });

    //hightlight the textfield on click event
    $('#shareit-field').click(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: The line you've posted is Javascript(or more specifically jQuery), you can't just nest PHP inside a Javascript file. The only time you can put PHP inside JS is when you're outputting that JS from inside a PHP file, is that the case?

Comment: I got a link assigned to each post in PHP and when that link is hovered it opens a box with the bookmarking links. I'm not too familiar with jQuery (as you can see), so I though it could be that easy.

Comment: Andrew, if you post up the code you're working with someone(perhaps myself) might be able to offer a suggestion or two, but without seeing more of the associated code it's hard to say if what you're asking is possible.

Comment: You're right, so I added the jQuery code in the original question and the PHP is like this if it helps any: `<li><a href="#" rel="shareit-posterous" class="shareit-sm"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/posterous_16.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Posterous" title="Posterous" /></a></li>`

Comment: Sorry Andrew, i was actually referring to the PHP code you're working with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must output the propper HTML to make it working.

Specifically, the href-attribute needs to contain the URL and the title separated with the | sign, like `<a href="http://example.com/post-url|post-title" rel="shareit" ...`.

That will enable the script you've posted above use a concrete URL and title.

As I don't know you PHP code from your theme I can not give any further hints on how to output the correct URL or title, but probably `<?php the_permalink(); ?>|<?php the_title(); ?>` might do it.

Take care, encodings do apply.